# how to query in solidity using the struct properties

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether

Before i explain anything about mu question i want to put my code so that i can refer it

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract GeoSpatialData{

    uint public SpatialDataCount = 0;
    
    struct GeoData{
        uint id;
        address owner_address;
        string data_name;
        string data_year;
        string data_description;
        string data_img_url;
        string data_url;
        string data_category;
        string data_published_date;
    }

    GeoData[] public geoDatas;

    mapping (uint => GeoData) public geodatas;
    // write function
    function createData(string memory _data_name,address _owner_address,string memory _data_year,string memory  _data_description,string memory _data_image_url,string memory _data_url,string memory _data_published_date,string memory _data_category,uint _id ) public{
        SpatialDataCount++;
        uint used_id = SpatialDataCount+_id;
        geoDatas.push(GeoData({id: used_id,owner_address:_owner_address,data_name:_data_name,data_year:_data_year,data_description:_data_description,data_img_url:_data_image_url,data_url:_data_url,data_category:_data_category,data_published_date:_data_published_date}));
        // geoDatas.push(Ge)
    }
    // read all data  function
    function readData() public{

    }

    // read single data function 
    function readSingle() public{

    }

}
```

I want to create a function to read single struct data using the id function which i make to be unique always
and then i also want to create a function by which i can read the whole struct as of now later i want to have a pagination functionality how can i achive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read unlimited amount of data from the chain via a single function, so getting all of the structs is not possible. Not unless you modify your own node and allow `eth_call` to be able to use unlimited gas.

If you need paginated access and your own id is not ordered, you can do something like:

```
GeoData[] public geoData;
mapping(uint => uint) idIndexMap; // mapping your id to array index

function getGeoData(uint256 id) public view returns (GeoData memory) {
  uint256 index = idIndexMap[id];
  return geoData[index];
}

function paginatedGetGeoData(uint256 offset, uint256 count) public view returns (GeoData[] memory) {
  GeoData[] memory data = new GeoData[](count);
  for (uint256 i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    data[i] = geoData[offset + i];
  }
  return data;
}
```